# How can I transfer parameters from one gpflow model to another to gain similar results?

Tags: python, gpflow

Suppose I have a trained model

```
m = gpflow.models.SVGP(
     likelihood=likelihood, kernel=kernel, inducing_variable=Z, num_data = len(X_train)
)
```

is it possible to transfer its parameters to another model and achieve similar results? For example

```
model = gpflow.models.SVGP(kernel=m.kernel,
                           likelihood=m.likelihood,
                           inducing_variable=m.inducing_variable,
                           num_data=m.num_data)
```

But this example fails since `model` has poor results. Are there some other parameters, which should be added to the signature, or it is impossible in principle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the SVGP (as well as VGP) model predictions crucially depend on the *q(u)* distribution parametrised by `model.q_mu` and `model.q_sqrt`. You can transfer all parameters (including those two) using

```py
params = gpflow.utilities.parameter_dict(model)
gpflow.utilities.multiple_assign(model, params)
```

(see [this notebook](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/intro_to_gpflow2.html#Copying-(hyper)parameter-values-between-models) for more context)